# How do I correct #NAME? entries in a data frame?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I am working on a problem on Kaggle.com. I have this data in which some columns have entries like "#NAME?" as follows. I know there is something. How do I correct these entires?

```
zzucnDH33KlmbkI4rLyQTA  3.5 1   phoenix   AZ    5   maddu   -112.006669 33.598922
ZztUsJyGDwPySepmXRG13g  3   0   tempe     AZ    52  maddu   -111.93526  33.4251549
zzucnDH33KlmbkI4rLyQTA  3.5 1   phoenix   AZ    15  ski pro -112.03603  33.509844
#NAME?                  2.5 1   glendale  AZ    11  maddu  -112.2252989 33.64243764
#NAME?                  4   1   phoenix   AZ    549 maddu  -112.079081       33.49112
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `comment.char` argument to "" :

```
read.table(text='zzucnDH33KlmbkI4rLyQTA  3.5 1   phoenix   AZ    5   maddu   -112.006669 33.598922
ZztUsJyGDwPySepmXRG13g  3   0   tempe     AZ    52  maddu   -111.93526  33.4251549
zzucnDH33KlmbkI4rLyQTA  3.5 1   phoenix   AZ    15  ski pro -112.03603  33.509844
#NAME?                  2.5 1   glendale  AZ    11  maddu  -112.2252989 33.64243764
#NAME?                  4   1   phoenix   AZ    549 maddu  -112.079081       33.49112',comment.char='',sep='\t')


                     V1  V2 V3       V4 V5  V6      V7        V8       V9
1 zzucnDH33KlmbkI4rLyQTA 3.5  1  phoenix AZ   5   maddu -112.0067 33.59892
2 ZztUsJyGDwPySepmXRG13g 3.0  0    tempe AZ  52   maddu -111.9353 33.42515
3 zzucnDH33KlmbkI4rLyQTA 3.5  1  phoenix AZ  15 ski pro -112.0360 33.50984
4                 #NAME? 2.5  1 glendale AZ  11   maddu -112.2253 33.64244
5                 #NAME? 4.0  1  phoenix AZ 549   maddu -112.0791 33.49112
```

Comment: I am still not getting it right. I used read.csv() with comment.char="". I do not think those entries are "comments". Those are thing which excel usually shows.

Comment: @user2474387 exactly , I setted the comments arguments to tell read.csv that they are not comments. The default value is `#`. Why do you get as a result?

Comment: same, no change at all. Let me give you details, please bear with me. Actually the original file was in JSON format. In JSON format values are there. But when I convert them into csv file, then I get "#NAME?". #NAMES? is coming in place of entries like "-_wk7WTa_--ZJWFF_i5v_w" etc. May be "fromJSON()" function is not able to read them properly. Should I add a separate question in more detail??

Comment: Personally, I would treat the problem before saving ( I amena I would save my file without the #NAME....).. I would loop over the fromJson result and replace the bad pattern. SO, definitely , yes it is a new question.